# Move the open/close marker of rich:simpleTogglePanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces, myfaces

I have a simpleTogglePanel set up as follows:

```html
<rich:simpleTogglePanel
    headerClass="myHeaderClass"
    opened="false"
    switchType="client" style="border: 0px;" bodyClass="myBodyClass">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText styleClass="panelHeader" value="#{myBean.header}"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="closeMarker">
        <h:outputText value="^"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="openMarker">
        <h:outputText value=">" />
    </f:facet>
    Content
</rich:simpleTogglePanel>
```

I want to move the open/close marker(which I have made ^ and > respectively to the left of the panel.

I have tried using float: left in myHeaderClass aswell as float:left !important and float:left;text-align: right.

Nowhere can I find anything that explains how to do this.The styling I found on sites where people were showing functionality of the simpleTogglePanel overall and this seemed to be all I didn't have.

I am using JSF 1.2(Apache MyFaces Implementation) and Richfaces 3.3.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now,just after posting this question I found the answer.

just add :

    .rich-stglpanel-marker{
     float: left;
    }

I don't know why this works,but it doesn't when I add it to my header class.
Anyway hopefully this is helpfull to other people aswell.Will post this as answer in 7 hours if no answer has been posted.If there is a cleaner/better way to do this please do tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS which govern the markers in `rich:simpleTogglePanel` is `rich-stglpnl-marker` as per [RichFaces reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_simpleTogglePanel.html) (scroll down for Classes names that define a component appearance section)

```
rich-stglpnl-marker     Defines styles for a wrapper <div> element of a marker
```

Whereas `headerClass` is applicable for header elements only.

```
headerClass    applicable to header elements
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,this cleared it up for me.Is there perhaps a way to define my own class for the markers similar to how I define the header class?

Comment: @Vinc No. You have to override the ones provided by RichFaces.